# display datagridview cell data in the textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i want to display my datagridview1 data in relevant textboxes. when i select any cell in the datagridview1 relevant data should be displayed in textboxes. 
here is the code i did

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
 ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
 Handles DataGridView1.CellClick


    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Me.Label8.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    Me.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    Me.TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    Me.ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    Me.ComboBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
    Me.TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
    Me.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
    Me.TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(8, i).Value
    Me.RichTextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(9, i).Value
    Me.Label14.Text = DataGridView1.Item(10, i).Value
End Sub
```

i did another code here it is

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender _
                           As System.Object, ByVal e As _
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                 Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

   Try
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow
            row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            Label8.Text = row.Cells("id").Value.ToString
            TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("firstname").Value.ToString
            TextBox2.Text = row.Cells("lastname").Value.ToString
            ComboBox1.Text = row.Cells("year").Value.ToString
            ComboBox2.Text = row.Cells("month").Value.ToString
            TextBox5.Text = row.Cells("gender").Value.ToString
            TextBox3.Text = row.Cells("address").Value.ToString
            TextBox4.Text = row.Cells("telephone").Value.ToString
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

however both codes are not working they give errors. inside the "" marks represent the column name

can anyone give me the solution in vb.net

Comment: You don't need any code.  Put the data into a list of some sort and then simply bind that list to both the grid and the individual controls.  What you want to happen will then happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

Dim i As Integer

With DataGridView1
    if e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        i = .CurrentRow.Index

        tbID.text = .Rows(i).Cells("id").Value.ToString
        tbFirstNametext = .Rows(i).Cells("firstname").Value.ToString
        tbLastNametext = .Rows(i).Cells("lastname").Value.ToString
        tbAddresstext = .Rows(i).Cells("address").Value.ToString
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this,

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

    namatxt.Text = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedCells(1).Value.ToString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
    Me.Label8.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
    Me.TextBox2.Text = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
    Me.ComboBox1.Text = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
    Me.ComboBox2.Text = row.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
    Me.TextBox5.Text = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
    Me.TextBox3.Text = row.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
    Me.TextBox4.Text = row.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = row.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
    Me.RichTextBox2.Text = row.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
    Me.Label14.Text = row.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works fine for me:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        tbID.Text = row.Cells("id").Value.ToString
        tbFirstName.Text = row.Cells("firstname").Value.ToString
        tbLastName.Text = row.Cells("lastname").Value.ToString
        tbAddress.Text = row.Cells("address").Value.ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

replace the names of the columns i have (i.e "id" "firstname" "lastname") etc with the name of your columns.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate through DataGridView rows with up and down keys and show the selected record in textboxes you can use this:

```
'declare variable

 Private DB As New databasenameDataSetTableAdapters.tablenameTableAdapter

'add constructor to your form

 Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
         InitializeComponent()
        'Setting KeyPreview To True makes sure that the Form1_KeyDown will always 
        'be called If a key Is pressed,
         Me.KeyPreview = True

      End Sub

Private Sub form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

Select Case e.KeyCode

'if else statement is there otherwise when going through the rows in grid

'it would show the previous row in textboxes instead of current one

'GetData is a select query you can generate by double clicking the dataset.xsd file in solution explorer

            Case Keys.Up
                Dim rowUp As Integer = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index

                If (rowUp <= 0) Then
                    rowUp = 0
                Else
                    rowUp = rowUp - 1
                End If

                Try
                    txtBox1.Text = DB.GetData.Rows(rowUp).Item(0).ToString
                    txtBox2.Text = DB.GetData.Rows(rowUp).Item(1).ToString
                    txtBox3.Text = DB.GetData.Rows(rowUp).Item(2).ToString
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
Exit Select

            Case Keys.Down

                Dim rowDown As Integer = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index

                If (rowDown >= DB.GetData.Rows.Count - 1) Then
                    rowDown = DB.GetData.Rows.Count - 1
                Else
                    rowDown = rowDown + 1
                End If

             Try
               txtBox1.Text = DB.GetData.Rows(rowDown).Item(0).ToString
               txtBox2.Text = DB.GetData.Rows(rowDown).Item(1).ToString
               txtBox3.Text = DB.GetData.Rows(rowDown).Item(2).ToString

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
 Exit Select
```

Another way of doing it use the datagridview CellEnter event

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
  Handles DataGridView1.CellEnter

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
        txtBox1.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        txtBox2.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString(), 

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
  Handles DataGridView1.CellEnter

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
        txtBox1.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        txtBox2.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString(), 

End Sub
```

Comment: Raju, I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwiese please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.